# Twitter bootstrap custom modification

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have the following codes:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">

   <div class="carousel-inner-image"><img src="mask.png" alt=""></div>

   <div class="item">
       <img width="821" height="498" src="slide-1.png"  alt="slide 1" />
   </div>

   <div class="item">
       <img width="821" height="498" src="slide-2.png"  alt="slide 2" />
   </div>

</div>
```

My problem is that, when I use right and left carousel controls to change the images, it adds active class to the first `<div class="carousel-inner-image">` and destroy the slides loop. I want right and left carousel controls to loop through only the `<div class="item">` not any `<div>`.

Is there any way to specify this or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to select only the elements that match class item, then you must define it in your jQuery functions, like `$( ".item" )`. You might probably want to do something like `$( ".carousel-inner > .item" )` which will select all items that have class item and that are children of the elements that have class carousel-inner.
Example:

```
$( ".carousel-inner > .item" ).hide(); 
// This will hide all elements with class item that are children of elements with class carousel-inner
```

You may also probably need to specify which of the .item you wish to select. The first child, the nth child, etc.

Comment: you did not get my question.